# Keep selected border effect on a radio button

Tags: html, css

I have two radio buttons. When selecting one, a blue border is marked. The problem is that if I click outside the button again, the radius stays checked but the border disappears.

How could I keep the blue border effect no matter where I click unless I select the other option.

And also how could I move the price span to the right and keep the product name on the left.

```
<style>
        .checkbox-custom, .radio-custom {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;   
        }
        .checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
        position: relative;
        }
        .checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before, .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
        content: '';
        background: #fff;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        }
        .checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
        background: rebeccapurple;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
        }
        .radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
        }
        .radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
        background: #000;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
        }
        .checkbox-custom:focus + .checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
        outline: 1px solid blue;
        width:50%;
        }
        .radio-custom-label{
        background: #f4f4f4;
        width: 50%;
        }
</style>

<div>
        <input id="pA" value="{{ pago_normal  }}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
        <label for="pA" class="radio-custom-label">ProductA
        <span>$100</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="pB" value="{{ pago_cuotas }}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
        <label for="pB" class="radio-custom-label">ProductB
        <span>$200</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Simply replace `:focus` with `:checked`.